# General topology models of projective plane

Tags: general-topology

I should prove that $RP^2$ is homeomorphic to the following quotient of the disk. Two point $p, q$ in the disk $D^2$ are equivalent if both have norm $1$ and $p = -q$.

My idea: I know that if I do the inclusion $i$ of the sphere $S^n$ into $\mathbb{R}^{n+1}-\{0\}$ and because the composition c: $S^n \rightarrow  \mathbb{R}^{n+1} - \{0\} \rightarrow RP^n$ is surjective, $c^{-1}([p]) = \{p, -p\}$. Thus $RP^n$ can be obtained as a quotient of the $n$-sphere under the equivalence relation that identifies every point $p$ to its opposite $-p$. So it I knew.

And I think that disk $D^2$, where points  $p, q$ are equivalent if both have norm $1$ and $p = -q$ is the same as sphere $S^2$ and then $RP^2$ can be obtained as a quotient of the $D^2$  that identifies every point $p$ to its opposite $-p$.

Comment: First, note that in order to get a sphere from a disk, you should identify all the boundary points of the disk with each other: set $p \sim q$ for all $p,q \in \partial D^n$.

Second, the question is already answered here: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1391724/real-projective-plane-is-same-as-identifying-antipodal-boundary-points-of-the-2

Comment: Third, here is the clue  to find other explanations.
Let $X$ be $D^n$ with opposite boundary points identified.
Note that $\partial D^n = S^{n-1}$, and $S^{n-1} / (p \sim -p) = \mathbb{R}P^{n-1}$, so $X$ is actually the disk $D^n$ glued to $\mathbb{R}P^{n-1}$ along the quotient map $S^{n-1} \to \mathbb{R}P^{n-1}$. Given that $X$ is homeomorphic to $\mathbb{R}P^{n}$ (this is exactly what you want), this gives rise to the cellular structure of $\mathbb{R}P^{n}$, which can be studied from the textbooks. It means that the desired fact must be repeated many times in the literature.

Comment: Thank you very much :)

Comment: Your solution is clear and nice and helped me. :)