# Fundamental group of the projective plane minus two points

Tags: algebraic-topology, fundamental-groups, projective-space

I want to compute the fundamental group of $\mathbb R \mathbb P_2 \backslash \{A,B\}$ (where $A$,$B$ are points) but I am stuck. I tried to use van Kampen's theorem bit I can't find two good subset (I tried $A=\mathbb R \mathbb P_2 \backslash \{A,B,p\}$ (where $p$ is anorher point) and $B=(\mathbb R \mathbb P_2 \backslash \{A,B\})^\circ$, but I can't manage to compute their fundamental groups).

Any hints? Am I on the right way with using Van Kampen, or should I try something else?

Comment: Hint: Try the square representation of $\Bbb{R}P^2$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, you can think of $\mathbb{R}\text{P}_{2}$ as the upper hemisphere of a $2$-sphere with antipodal maps on the boundary identified.  (See here: [Real Projective Plane is Same as Identifying Antipodal Boundary Points of The $2$-Disc.](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1391724/real-projective-plane-is-same-as-identifying-antipodal-boundary-points-of-the-2)).
Then, choose any two points on the upper hemisphere, and get rid of those. You can continually deform the resulting space into the boundary of $\mathbb{R}\text{P}_{2}$ along with an arc joining any two points on the boundary. This space is the same the wedge sum of two copies of $S_{1}$, and by Van - Kampen's theorem, the fundamental group of this space is the free product of two copies of $\mathbb{Z}$, i.e. $\mathbb{Z} * \mathbb{Z}$.